# How to checkout Jenkinsfile of the source branch in a PR

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

The Jenkinsfile across branches are different and I would like to execute the Jenkinsfile in the source branch of the pull request.

I am using Bitbucket Jenkins plugin to do it.

There are two variables which I tried using in the configuration. But both failed.

- ${sourceBranch}

  ```
  [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
  [BFA] No failure causes found
  [BFA] Done. 0s
  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/${sourceBranch}:refs/remotes/origin/${sourceBranch} --prune" returned status code 128:
  stdout: 
  stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${sourceBranch}
  ```
- ${GIT_BRANCH}

  ```
  [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
  [BFA] No failure causes found
  [BFA] Done. 0s
  hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/${GIT_BRANCH}:refs/remotes/origin/${GIT_BRANCH} --prune" returned status code 128:
  stdout: 
  stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${GIT_BRANCH}
  ```

Please let me know the variable which can point to the source branch of the pull request in the incoming webhook.

Comment: Incoming webhook??? or Incoming remote trigger url request to jenkins?
Where are you accessing those variables??? In the `Source Code Management` section??

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.  That plugin is designed to build the branch, including the jenkinsfile of that branch.  The problem should be in updating the PR to fix the Jenkinsfile, instead of you trying to write some script to figure out the upstream/parent branch, followed by somehow copying that jenkinsfile into the workspace.  I'm not saying it's not possible, but the script you'll write will be a pain. If you google "git get parent branch" you'll see some examples of the complexity you'll run into.

Comment: @SVMadhavaReddy Bitbucket is configured to make an API call to Jenkins using Webhook. It triggers the build which in effect goes to pick up a Jenkinsfile from a particular branch of a particular repository. At the moment, the branch from where the Jenkisnfile is checked out is hardcoded to the Job. I want to be able to checkout the Jenkinsfile of the branch which is the source branch of the pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Bitbucket branch source plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin) and this works without further ado. Just add your Bitbucket project as a job in Jenkins, it scans all repos including all branches and pull requests and creates the corresponding jobs. No need to play around with these variables.

If you want to use the Jenkinsfile from another branch, you need to copy it from there by cherry-picking the commits that changed the Jenkinsfile in that branch:

```
git cherry-pick <HASH>
```